# When changing theme's font, why does font-size attribute not work?

Tags: css, fonts

Since my theme's font [doesn't support my language](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/344767/64282), I add this code to style.css to change the font. It does work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'new-baskerville';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.eot');
    src: local('new-baskerville'), url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.woff') format('woff');
}

.new-baskerville{font-family: 'new-baskerville' !important;}

        body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, li, a, #menu-main-menu li a, #menu-main-menu li span, font-size: 20 em;{
    font-family: 'new-baskerville' !important;
}
```

However, the font-size attribute doesn't work. Even if I set it as 20 em, it still the same size. Why does this happen?

<sup>(That code is generated by [Use Any Font](https://dineshkarki.com.np/use-any-font) plugin)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to sound too critical, but you might want to review [how to properly introduce a new font](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp), and apply font styles content.  The declaration that you presented appears to have a couple of issues:

- Using ".new-baskerville" would cause everything with the class "new-baskerville" (and ***ONLY*** those with that class) to appear with font-family of new-baskerville.
- Using "!Important" in this context can cause issues. It should really only be used to override a locally defined, or "inline" style.
- The following line is completely malformed:

  ```
  body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, li, a, #menu-main-menu li a, #menu-main-menu li span, font-size: 20 em;{
      font-family: 'new-baskerville' !important;
  }
  ```
- I believe you were trying to do something more like the following code example, but that is still problematic, because it applies the same font-size to everything:

  ```
  body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, li, a, #menu-main-menu li a, #menu-main-menu li span{
      font-size: 20 em;
      font-family: "new-baskerville",helvetica, san-serif; /* providing fallbacks for browsers that may not be able to interpret new-baskerville */
   }
  ```

Instead, individual items should have their own relative font-sizes. Also, "em" sizes are relative.  So, you might start by applying a default font size to the body.  This will cause all the other font-size declarations ("em", "rem", etc) to adjust "relative to" the body's default.  I would recommend changes similar to this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'new-baskerville';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.eot');
    src: url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/190811081519New-Baskerville.woff') format('woff');
    }

/* Provide a base font size for the entire page */
body { 
    font-family: 'new-baskerville',garamond,san-serif;
    font-size: 14px; 
}

h1 { font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold; }
h2 { font-size: 1.75em; font-weight: bold; }
h3 { font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; }
h4 { font-size: 1.45em; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;}
... etc...
```

**EDIT:**   Something you might want to follow up on ... Not all web servers are setup with mime types configured for eot, woff, woff2, etc.  You might need to [setup mime types](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/configuring_mimetypes_on_the_server/) for your server. BTW ... the author doesn't mention woff2. That mime type is font/woff2.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work. I think the problem is not there, but that the only first part of the code doesn't change the font. Although `* {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; 
}` works, changing `Courier New` to `new-baskerville` with the src like that doesn't work

Comment: If Courier New works, but not your new font. You might check the server configuration for mime types. I've edited my answer to include a link to one article that tells you how.

Answer (score -1):

You have at least one syntax error in your code.
Start by changing this part:

```
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, li, a, #menu-main-menu li a, #menu-main-menu li span, font-size: 20 em;{
    font-family: 'new-baskerville' !important;
}
```

To this:

```
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, li, a, #menu-main-menu li a, #menu-main-menu li span {
    font-family: 'new-baskerville' !important;
    font-size: 20 em;
}
```

The styles have to be inside the brackets. The `font-size` style was outside the brackets in the list of elements to target. The syntax error (probably from the `;`) caused everything inside the bracket fail.

Comment: A comment is useful when a downvote is added. Without a comment no one can learn why the answer is bad and what should be done to improve.